# How to deploy a website in cPanel made by tailwind css, vite and Laravel 9 with breeze?

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, breeze

I have completed an e-commerce website. I want to live this website in a live server, (Namecheap Cpanel). When I start this site on the local server by commanding php artisan serve. I also need to start another command **npm run dev**. I have completed this website **by Lavavel, Laravel breeze, tailwind css, daisyUI and vite**. I need your help to deploy this project properly. Also, I need another help that is I also want to simply deploy this project after the new update.

Comment: You should not use php artisan serve on a production server. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment